# Android ProGuard jar dependencies in aar and apk files

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, proguard

I am trying to use ProGuard for an Android project that is building with Android Studio 0.8.14 to reduce apk size. Without ProGuard the project builds and runs happily. The structure of the project is that we have many apk files and each reference at least 2 aar files, this is how we share algorithms between the apks. The aars reference jar files, one of them is joda time, just for an example.

I am trying to turn on ProGuard for one of the apk modules, I am doing this:

For the apk project in build.gradle I set runProguard true for the debug build.

I have specified 
-dontwarn org.joda.convert.**
to get rid of some jodatime warnings e.g.

> Warning: org.joda.time.DateMidnight: can't find referenced class
>   org.joda.convert.FromString

(There are other warnings by other libraries which I hide with the same method).

I also specified -dontobfuscate because my primary aim now is reducing apk size but if I comment that out nothing changes.

Then I run

gradlew.bat -p {projectname} assembleDebug clean --debug --stacktrace

And the result is this stack trace (the stack trace is longer, I believe this is the more interesting part, if you want to see the full stack trace please let me know).

> 12:44:29.019 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: Can't read
>   [C:\Projects\Marvin2\InCabAndroid\incabvehicleinspection\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\InCabAndroid\AndroidCoreLib\unspecified\libs\joda-time-2.5.jar(;;;;;;!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)]
>   (Duplicate zip entry
>   [joda-time-2.5.jar:org/joda/time/base/AbstractDateTime.class])
>   12:44:29.020 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:232) 12:44:29.020
>   [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   at
>   proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:202) 12:44:29.020
>   [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   at
>   proguard.OutputWriter.writeOutput(OutputWriter.java:253) 12:44:29.020
>   [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 58 more 12:44:29.020
>   [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: Duplicate zip entry
>   [joda-time-2.5.jar:org/joda/time/base/AbstractDateTime.class]
>   12:44:29.020 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   proguard.io.JarWriter.getOutputStream(JarWriter.java:139) 12:44:29.020
>   [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   at
>   proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:105)
>   12:44:29.020 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:105)
>   12:44:29.020 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:92)
>   12:44:29.020 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   proguard.io.ClassRewriter.read(ClassRewriter.java:68) 12:44:29.020
>   [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   at
>   proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
>   12:44:29.020 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
>   12:44:29.021 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
>   12:44:29.021 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   proguard.io.JarReader.read(JarReader.java:65) 12:44:29.021 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   at
>   proguard.io.DirectoryPump.readFiles(DirectoryPump.java:65)
>   12:44:29.021 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   proguard.io.DirectoryPump.pumpDataEntries(DirectoryPump.java:53)
>   12:44:29.021 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:228) 12:44:29.021
>   [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 60 more

I have a feeling that this error is the result of bringing in joda time via the aar modules plus the apk itself, I just do not know how to get around this.

For Duplicate zip entry the ProGuard manual says

> The standard Android build process automatically specifies the input
>   jars for you. There may not be an easy way to filter them to remove
>   these warnings. You could remove the duplicate resource files manually
>   from the input and the libraries.

Also for classes a similar statement is made in the ProGuard manual:

> The standard Android build process automatically specifies the input
>   jars for you. There may not be an easy way to filter them to remove
>   these notes. You could remove the duplicate classes manually from your
>   libraries.

So I am a bit lost about what to do next. If someone experienced with ProGuard has an idea, could you please share it with me? Thank you.

Comment: It's a little hard to tell without more information on how everything in your project is packaged, but it looks like you're including joda-time twice. Perhaps your AARs are mispackaged and are including those classes when they shouldn't?

Comment: What you are saying is that AARs should not contain joda time class files? My understanding (might be wrong) is that the build will take all referenced aars and extract ("explode") them and then merge them together into the apk. This merge works w/o proguard. I think the input gradle passes on to proguard is everything in the exploded directories which contain multiple joda time instances for each aar file. And each aar file does use joda time, they fail to build without it. So I do not know how I could change this or if I am misunderstanding something in this.

Comment: You shouldn't bundle the classes multiple times. Duplicate copies of the same class aren't merged, but cause an error. Even if you weren't proguarding, you'd have problems at the dex phase anyway (the "multiple dex files define..." error).

Comment: As I said without ProGuard all apps build and work well. I do not understand how I would achieve not bundling e.g. Joda Time classes multiple times if I have 2 aar modules that use Joda Time classes and have an apk that uses Joda Time classes plus uses code from the 2 aar modules. Could you please explain how you would reference Joda Time in this case?

Comment: Different modules can depend on something like Joda Time without actually including its classes in their distribution.

Comment: It would be great if this worked. Could you please tell me a keyword that I could search for on the internet to learn how to reference something without actually including it?

Comment: `provided` is the compile scope you may be looking for